# Android CheckBox is hard to tap

Tags: android, checkboxes

What are some good ways to make the `CheckBox` widget easier to tap in Android apps? In my app, *both* the `CheckBox` *and* the thing-behind-and-next-to-the-`CheckBox` are tappable, serving distinct functions. I've noticed that it's hard to target the `CheckBox` with my index finger, and I have slender fingers.

For context, this `CheckBox` is on the right side of a `ListView` adapter. The left side of the item has two `TextView`s. The `ListView` is a shopping list; the user taps the item in the shopping list to see a detailed description in a dialog, and taps the `CheckBox` to mark the item as purchased. Therefore, I can't just make the whole item tappable to toggle the `CheckBox`, as there would be no good way to view the detail dialog.

I've considered making some kind of ghost widget surrounding the `CheckBox`, which triggers a `CheckBox` toggle, just to make it a bigger target for fingers, but is that good UI design? Is there a best-practice solution?

Comment: Why is the checkbox distinct from the row/ect item the checkbox is on? This isn't usually a problem because apps use checkboxes in a list where the whole row is clickable, the actual checkbox is too small but it's not mean to be the strict tap target.

Comment: How large are your [touch target areas](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1085)?

Comment: @dnbrv I kinda take it he's using the default Android checkbox size and nothing else. That checkbox isn't meant to be the only tap target as I said.

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree that, if the item isn't tappable with a distinct function, then the whole item should toggle the CheckBox, so I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a TouchDelegate to increase the clickable area of the checkbox itself.  You can find an answer on SO indicating how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343222/is-there-an-example-of-how-to-use-a-touchdelegate-in-android-to-increase-the-siz).

Copy-pasting:

```
final View parent = (View) delegate.getParent();
parent.post( new Runnable() {
    // Post in the parent's message queue to make sure the parent
    // lays out its children before we call getHitRect()
    public void run() {
        final Rect r = new Rect();
        delegate.getHitRect(r);
        r.top -= 4;
        r.bottom += 4;
        parent.setTouchDelegate( new TouchDelegate( r , delegate));
    }
});
```

Comment: Also useful is the [android training page](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate)